# how to return byte[] to download pdf in angular

Tags: c#, .net

```
[HttpGet()]
[Route("{customerId}")]
public virtual async Task<FileContentResult> ApplicationFormDownload([FromRoute] long customerId)
{
    ApplicationFormQuery applicationFormQuery = new ApplicationFormQuery() { CustomerId = customerId };
    var responce = await _mediator.Send(applicationFormQuery);
    return new FileContentResult(responce, "application/pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the PDF in a new tab you can do it like this:

Backend:

```
[HttpGet()]
[Route("{customerId}")]
public virtual async Task<FileContentResult> ApplicationFormDownload([FromRoute] long customerId)
{
    var base64String = GetTheFile(customerId);
    return Ok(base64String);
}
```

Frontend:

```
this._backendService.getFile()
  .subscribe(response => {
    const pdfWindow = window.open();
    if (pdfWindow) {
      pdfWindow.document.title = 'Any title';
      pdfWindow.document.body.innerHTML = `<iframe type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, ${encodeURI(response)}'></iframe>`;
    }
  });
```

Comment: return new FileContentResult(responce, "application/pdf");
I want to download the file, i am getting response as bytes. can you please answer